# Spring OAuth2 additional permision

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I need to add additional restriction to authenticate users. My User model has a field 'active'. It is false, when User registers, but not activate his account with hash from mail. Now, even if User is not active he gets access_token from Oauth. 
How should I configure this? 
I was thinking about SpringSecurityInterceptor, but I'm not sure about confusing Spring Security with OAuth2.
This is my SpringOAuth2.0 configuration:

```
   @Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/**")
                ))
                .authorizeRequests()

                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/rest/oauth/token");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("USER")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)


                  .secret("123456");
        }

    }

}
```

And also Spring security

```
    @Configuration
@Order(2147483640)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/")
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new UserLoginSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {

        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want your authorization server to grant an access token for a user that is not activated?

You could let your `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername` throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` if the user exists, but is not activated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already done it with UserDetails interface. Now my User entity implements this interface. There are methods responsible for checking if user is active, his account is not expired etc.